# SignInWithApple is not defined in IONIC Project

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

#### Scenario:

I am trying to add identification via Apple and `Firebase` for my IONIC 4 application.

So I made my installation:

`npm i cordova-plugin-apple-login`

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apple-login`

Then I added in my service :

```
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

declare var SignInWithApple: any;

export class AuthService {

  constructor(public fAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public fb: Facebook,
              public google: GooglePlus) {}

    async loginApple() {

        SignInWithApple.request({requestedScopes: [ SignInWithApple.Scope.Email, SignInWithApple.Scope.FullName ]})
            .then((appleCredential) => {
                const credential =  new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(appleCredential.identityToken);
                this.fAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log('Login successful');
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('error:' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            });
    }


}
```

#### Problem:

This is the method I find everywhere on the internet, but it gives me the error:

`SignInWithApple is not defined`

I also tried this :

#### Scenario:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple`

`npm i --save @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple`

```
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import { SignInWithApple,
    AppleSignInResponse,
    AppleSignInErrorResponse,
    ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest } from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple';

export class AuthService {

  constructor(public fAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public fb: Facebook,
              public google: GooglePlus) {}

    async loginApple() {

            try {
                const appleCredential: AppleSignInResponse = await SignInWithApple.signin({
                    requestedScopes: [
                        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,
                        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeEmail
                    ]
                });
                const credential = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
                    appleCredential.identityToken
                );
                this.fAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log('Login successful', res);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
    }
}
```

#### Problem:

```
Class not found
```

I don't find much explanation on the documentation ...

In both I have an error that I do not understand, what is the method to keep and how to correct it ?

An idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Are u testing on a device?

Comment: Yes i tested on an android smartphone